# Checkout totals html template change

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, totals

I've a strange problem with checkout page and totals row. Originally in module tax in file subtotal.html there is

```
<!-- ko if: !isBothPricesDisplayed() && !isIncludingTaxDisplayed() -->
<tr class="totals sub">
    <th data-bind="i18n: title" class="mark" scope="row"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I want to replace this with div but:

- when I add some html after </tr> it doesn't appear
- when I replace <tr class="totals sub"> with <div> on page it is replaced to
- when I add some text after <!-- /ko --> it also doesn't show on page

Why it is working so strange? How can I debug it?

Comment: Have you deployed content after updating the text in template file.. Please note that the text displays from pub/static folder, just mentioning if you don't have that idea.

Answer (score -1):

For debugging purpose you can edit subtotal.html file from pub/static folder, it will reflect instantly on frontend. 
if you update original subtotal.html file then you have to run deploy command every time.